# Solarized theme for Terminal

Tags: terminal, color

I've installed the [Solarized](https://github.com/tomislav/osx-lion-terminal.app-colors-solarized) theme for Terminal.app and imported it. But my Terminal is **all** gray, I don't get color highlighting on anything. Not even running Python terminal generates any color. How can I get the color highlighting working properly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Solarized themes the bright green, yellow, blue, and cyan foreground colors seem to be almost the same as the default foreground color.

[image]

Or if you were expecting it to add color to new places, it doesn't. Terminal setting files only change the settings that can also be changed from Terminal's preferences, like the values of ANSI colors.

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks. I guess I was expecting a more distinguished color output from my Terminal, i.e. like one can have with `ls -G` or any editor with colored syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want coloured output from ls, look here https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized